# Downloading PDFs by using node.js results in broken files

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, pdf, download

I am trying to download a number of PDF files from list (var urls) which contains the URLs. The download itself works but the resutlting PDF files are broken, meaning I can save them in my folder but I cannot open them. Is there anyone who has an idea?
Here is the code:

```
var urls=require('./paperURLs.json');
DOWNLOAD_DIR = './paper/';

function readFile(callback) {
  if(urls.length > 0) {
     var setFile = urls.shift(),
     file_name = url.parse(setFile).pathname.split('/').pop(),
     trial = setFile.split('/').pop(),
     file = fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + trial);
     http.get(setFile, function(res){
         res.on('error', function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
        res.on('data', function(data){
            file.write(data);
            console.log(setFile + ' started');
        });
        res.on('end', function(){ 
            console.log(setFile + ' completed, moving on');
            readFile(callback);
        });
    });
  } 
}

 readFile();
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you're not closing the file, which *could* cause some problems. Also, a better/easier way to do this might be to just pipe the streams together instead of doing it manually:

```
http.get(setFile, function(res) {
  res.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
  res.pipe(file).on('close', function() {
    console.log(setFile + ' completed, moving on');
    readFile(callback);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the same issue. If I do "console.log(res.headers['content-type']);" I get "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1". Maybe it's the wrong content type?

Comment: If you're expecting a pdf, then yes, that's the wrong Content-Type.

Comment: How can I change it? By passing it with the http.get request?

Comment: If the path to the remote file is correct, then you will need to start checking other requirements to download the file, such as cookies, tokens, etc. Does the downloaded html file give any clues?